# How to get CDATA text whether in APEX or Javascript from the below RSS feed example I only end up with null values

Tags: xml, lwc-dom, rss, lwc-xml

[image: Title is missing here which is highlighted in yellow]

```xml
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:abacus="http://www.abacusemedia.com/webvisioncloud/" xmlns:media="http://www.abacusemedia.com/webvisioncloud/">
  <channel>
    <atom:link href="https://forecourttrader.co.uk/17230.rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <title><![CDATA[Forecourt Trader - Latest Forecourt News]]></title>
    <link>https://forecourttrader.co.uk</link>
    <description><![CDATA[https://forecourttrader.co.uk]]></description>
    <image>
      <url>https://forecourttrader.co.uk/magazine/dest/graphics/logo/logo.png</url>
      <title><![CDATA[Forecourt Trader - Latest Forecourt News]]></title>
      <link>https://forecourttrader.co.uk</link>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[Hereford forecourt achieves 20% increase in shop and fuel sales after joining Murco]]></title>
      <link>https://forecourttrader.co.uk/latest-news/hereford-forecourt-achieves-20-increase-in-shop-and-fuel-sales-after-joining-murco/648716.article</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">https://forecourttrader.co.uk/latest-news/hereford-forecourt-achieves-20-increase-in-shop-and-fuel-sales-after-joining-murco/648716.article</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[Following a chance meeting with Murco at the April 2019 Forecourt Show at the NEC, Karl Hawkins of the Forge Filling Station in Wormbridge, Hereford, is now seeing a 20% increase in shop and fuel sales from his village forecourt.]]></description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 24 Sep 2020 11:57:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <enclosure type="image/jpeg" length="0" url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/7/3/6/217736_ftmurcoforgefillingstationwormbridge_774984_crop.jpg" />
      <abacus:image>
        <abacus:alt><![CDATA[FT Murco Forge Filling Station, Wormbridge]]></abacus:alt>
        <abacus:size>
          <abacus:data-size-mobile>280x188</abacus:data-size-mobile>
        </abacus:size>
        <abacus:url>https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net</abacus:url>
      </abacus:image>
      <media:content url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/7/3/6/217736_ftmurcoforgefillingstationwormbridge_774984_crop.jpg" type="image/jpeg" medium="image">
        <media:thumbnail url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/7/3/6/217736_ftmurcoforgefillingstationwormbridge_774984_crop.jpg" />
      </media:content>
      <abacus:newstype>N</abacus:newstype>
      <abacus:byline><![CDATA[#3108¦John Wood[john-wood]((10))#]]></abacus:byline>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[JTI launches two schemes designed to tackle problem of cigarette butt littering]]></title>
      <link>https://forecourttrader.co.uk/latest-news/jti-launches-two-schemes-designed-to-tackle-problem-of-cigarette-butt-littering/648683.article</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">https://forecourttrader.co.uk/latest-news/jti-launches-two-schemes-designed-to-tackle-problem-of-cigarette-butt-littering/648683.article</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[Tobacco company JTI has announced two new schemes designed to change consumer behaviour around cigarette butt littering.]]></description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 24 Sep 2020 11:57:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <enclosure type="image/jpeg" length="0" url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/6/1/7/217617_jtisigiveabuttooh_657387_crop.jpg" />
      <abacus:image>
        <abacus:alt><![CDATA[JTI's I Give A Butt OOH]]></abacus:alt>
        <abacus:size>
          <abacus:data-size-mobile>280x188</abacus:data-size-mobile>
        </abacus:size>
        <abacus:url>https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net</abacus:url>
      </abacus:image>
      <media:content url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/6/1/7/217617_jtisigiveabuttooh_657387_crop.jpg" type="image/jpeg" medium="image">
        <media:thumbnail url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/6/1/7/217617_jtisigiveabuttooh_657387_crop.jpg" />
      </media:content>
      <abacus:newstype>N</abacus:newstype>
      <abacus:byline><![CDATA[#3108¦John Wood[john-wood]((10))#]]></abacus:byline>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[PRA demands corrections after press claims motorists advised use petrol stations only if they “really need to”]]></title>
      <link>https://forecourttrader.co.uk/latest-news/pra-demands-corrections-after-press-claims-motorists-advised-use-petrol-stations-only-if-they-really-need-to/648665.article</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">https://forecourttrader.co.uk/latest-news/pra-demands-corrections-after-press-claims-motorists-advised-use-petrol-stations-only-if-they-really-need-to/648665.article</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[The PRA is demanding corrections from two major regional newspapers after they wrongly claimed the government was advising motorists not to stop at petrol stations “unless you really need to”. The Evening Standard in London and the Liverpool Echo both carried stories about the tightening of restrictions and new advice ...]]></description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 23 Sep 2020 13:25:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <enclosure type="image/jpeg" length="0" url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/5/8/9/217589_standardheadline_35079_crop.jpg" />
      <abacus:image>
        <abacus:alt><![CDATA[Standard Headline]]></abacus:alt>
        <abacus:size>
          <abacus:data-size-mobile>280x188</abacus:data-size-mobile>
        </abacus:size>
        <abacus:url>https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net</abacus:url>
      </abacus:image>
      <media:content url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/5/8/9/217589_standardheadline_35079_crop.jpg" type="image/jpeg" medium="image">
        <media:thumbnail url="https://d1haa5elnw3u00.cloudfront.net/pictures/280x188/5/8/9/217589_standardheadline_35079_crop.jpg" />
      </media:content>
      <abacus:newstype>N</abacus:newstype>
      <abacus:byline><![CDATA[#3108¦John Wood[john-wood]((10))#]]></abacus:byline>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I tried below with xmlString and DOM where as other non CDATA sections text fetched correctly.

```js
 item.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).textContent;
var rssArticleTitle = doc1.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].nodeValue; //This is returning Null Value
```

where doc1 has a RSS Response.
please suggest me how to proceed in order to fetch the Required Text inside CDATA

Comment: The CDATA in the example is incorrectly formed. It is `<![CDATA[text]]>` - the open square brackets are matched by closing ones. Is this a mistake here or in the actual response you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Phil I have added the actual code and its a mistake in this post previously. The cdata text required like from       <title><![CDATA[JTI launches two schemes designed to tackle problem of cigarette butt littering]]></title>